# How safe is a password protected Excel file?

Tags: encryption, excel

I have a need to send a 3rd party regular Excel files.

I currently use excel password protection on the file itself and the password I use is known by the 3rd party.

However, today I [read a thread on this forum](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/260169/is-it-safe-to-store-account-credentials-in-an-excel-sheet-protected-with-a-passw) that appears to say it is unsafe to password-protect an Excel file.  But this is counter to my understanding because I believe Excel uses 256-bit AES encryption which is currently unbreakable.

However the thread also talks about individual features of Excel and I am finding it difficult to separate the file password encryption from the feature protection, like protect a sheet in a workbook or cell protection.

So can someone advise if I place a password on the file such that it can not be opened, is it safe (within the limits of 256-bit encryption) or not?

BTW, I am using M365, I am not bothered by over-the-shoulder or cut-and-paste hacks as that is the 3rd parties problem from a data protection point of view.

Comment: "is it safe" -- from what? The Answers on the thread you linked appear to answer your question directly unless there is a particular threat that you have not disclosed.

Comment: Older versions of Office used weak encryption, which may explain why there's warnings against relying on it. But such advice is outdated; Office has used decent encryption since 2007.

Comment: Schroder, clearly wasn't good enough for me, but the answer from ThoriumBR provided exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES-256 is the gold standard when it comes to symmetric encryption.  However, the caveat here is the strength of the key.

If the key used is a 256-bit randomly generated key generated by a CSPRNG, then [AES-256 is highly resistant to brute force attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/how-much-would-it-cost-in-u-s-dollars-to-brute-force-a-256-bit-key-in-a-year).

However, if the encryption key is derived from a password, as is the case with Excel, then the weak links here are:

- the strength of the password
- the strength of the password derivation function that is used to derive the encryption key from the password

According to [this answer on crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47463/password-protected-excel-files), modern version of Excel use 50,000 rounds of salted SHA256 hashing to derive an encryption key from a password.

Nowadays, hashing rigs built using a few thousand dolars worth of ASIC hardware can do over 100 tera-hashes per second.  So, such a rig would be able attempt cracking the Excel file at the rate of about 2 billion passwords per second (100T / 50,000 = 2 billion).

So, if the password is on a password list (such as [rockyou.txt](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/wjburns/common-password-list-rockyoutxt)), the password would be cracked in a matter of seconds.

As another way of looking at it, consider a password 8 characters long, consisting of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and digits (i.e. each character could be one of 62 possible symbols).  Such a password would have 2.18 * 10<sup>14</sup> possible combinations 62<sup>8</sup> = 2.18 * 10<sup>14</sup>).  A rig like the one above could crack this password in a little over a day (2.18 * 10<sup>14</sup> / 2 billion = 109170 seconds = ~1.2 days).

Comment: That is an excellent answer., thank you, exactly what I needed. Whilst I profess the password could be better, at 13 characters long with a mixture of characters, I believe the security is good enough for anything, except a determined attack.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Properly implemented AES-256 encryption is, at this time, unbreakable.  File password protection seems to be built on this and should be fine.

Feature protection seems to be a function of the editor, not backed in cryptography, it therefor should not be trusted for security.

If one is unsure of the security of encryption features in a program, putting a file in an encrypted zip is always an option.

Comment: Excel documents from modern versions of Office (xlsx) _are_ a ZIP archive. They use the OpenXML standard.